# Why does my computer sometimes not identify my wireless network, or others, that it always connects to?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a vista operating system.

Sometimes my computer will not connect to the wireless network (internet) when I start up my laptop. This happens at different places on occasion, and it is very random. It tries to connect, but can not identify the network (it does recognize the wifi name). So at the end it connects, but with limited connectivity. It can not be the hardware because all other computers connect to it fine at the same time. And it happens at different places, mostly home, but sometimes at coffee shops, etc. And then in a day or two when I start up my laptop it is all of a sudden working again. (restart does not solve the problem).

I have tried all the trouble shooting options windows offers, restarting the notebook, switch modem on and off, switch laptop wifi on and of, deleted the wifi memory from the laptop and reconnected with the password as if it was the first time, everything.

If it does not work at one place it does not mean it won't work at another. Example it won't work at home, then I go to coffee shop and it works, then get back home and it don't.

Anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your other computers work, and that your the problem occurs at a number of places, it could be that your wireless adapter/wireless card (the thing that lets you connect to wi-fi) is the problem. It could be that it doesn't support WPA/WPA2 encryption. I'm not completely sure that this is the problem since you state that it only happens sometimes.

Wireless networks can use either WEP, WPA or WPA2 (there might be others, but these three appear to be the most common) encryption to protect their passwords. WEP is not as secure (you can crack it in around 10 minutes if you know how). WPA is more secure, with WPA2 being the best, but some wireless adapters don't support WPA or WPA2. Try updating your network drivers (if you haven't already).

Comment: I already updated it :/. Well yesterday my wireless worked fine at home, but tonight when i got home and turned on the computer it didn't work anymore, or 'not identify'. But it will most probably work tomorrow again, or Monday at the latest, taking from previous experiences...

Comment: Also check the power settings of the card... Although not logical because it sometimes occurs at startup, it's one to look at. Also check the adapter roaming aggression, channel and connection speed. The rate thing is strange because similar things happen on a gigabit LAN where the card auto-negotiates but you get limited connectivity... dropping the card to 100Mbps fixes the problem...